How to solve infinite re render of react-hook-form?
I am trying to create a simple form in React using react-hook-form library.
I have added different validations and other things to the form.
But I am getting below console error.
console error:
Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency arr
I am not even using a state and useEffect.
I tried to debug by removing form fields one by one.
But still couldn't figure out why the re-render is occurring.
I even tried to see render count using renderCount. The value of renderCount remains constant when I am entering values in username input box, but UI is lagging and am getting console errors for "maximum update depth exceeded"
Code Sandbox Link:
Code Sandbox Link

Can you share a Code Sandbox?

useForm and useFieldArray are two custom hooks which internally uses useState and useEffect possibly, you need to check which property you are calling again and again from your jsx(possibly) or any other function and check for circular dependency which might be causing the issue

@AhmedAbdelbaset I have added the Code Sandbox link.

I was reviewing the Code Sandbox but i can't see any error, did you already fix it?

The problem is the devtools is not optimized well. Comment it out when there is no need.

@AhmedAbdelbaset Thanks for your reply. It works fine when Devtool is commented.

As pointed out by @AhmedAbdelbaset, the problem is that DevTools are not optimized.
After commenting it out, the form works perfectly fine.
